# Выделение selected элемента QListView

Tags: c++, qt, qlistview

Ситуация: при нажатии на элемент QListView, он выделяется синим, когда сам ListView в фокусе:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и становится темным, когда ListView теряет фокус:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В некоторых ситуациях мне нужно выбрать и произвести "нажатие" определенный элемент в списке без "клика" на него, я использую:

```
on_listView_clicked(index);
ui->listView->setCurrentIndex(index);
```

нужный объект выделяется, программа работает исправно, но при таком выборе нет никакого выделения в самом ListView. То есть элемент выбран, если вывести currentIndex ListView, то всё будет правильно, но никакого цветного выделения такая реализация не выдает, что не очень интуитивно понятно при работе. Подскажите, как решить эту проблемку?

Comment: А у меня все работает и выделяется. Возможно Вы некорректно работаете с ListView? Сейчас оформлю ответ как я работаю

Comment: А еще, кажется, что я не правильно понял вопрос. Можете ли Вы уточнить? При программном выборе у вас совсем не подсвечивается выбранный элемент списка или просто Вам не нравится, что цвет не синий, а серый?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переопределите стиль для виджета и будет вам счастье

```
ui->listView->setStyleSheet("selection-background-color: blue;");
```

или пропишите тот же самый стиль в самом ui